# bootstrap timepicker default time to false but to show PM instead of AM

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I don't want to show default time and I can do this with the code below:

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({defaultTime:false});
```

When I open the time picker it shows 1:00 AM

Is it possible to show PM as selected rather AM ? ie default time which is shown on time picker need to show PM as selected.

Answer (score 1):

"showMeridian : false" 24hr mode, if it is false 12hr mode (default)

like this :

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
  defaultTime:false,
  showMeridian : false
});
```

is this exactly what you want?

Comment: I need to show 12 hour format. I need to show "PM" as default rather than  "AM" when someone click on the textbox.

Comment: if u define showMeridian parameter as true, appear as 12hr format and if you someone click textbox :

$('textbox').click(function(){
  $('#timepicker').timepicker({
    defaultTime:false,
    showMeridian : false
  });
});

timepicker appear as PM format.

Comment: Doesn't work. See the image for more details: http://postimg.org/image/n8h02exqn/